# the ocelot is not taming

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have tried to tame it but it still looks like an ocelot even though I can put it in breeding mode. I can't make it sit it does not follow me the only thing I can do is put it in breeding mode. How can I tame it

Comment: Are you in the snapshots? You can't turn ocelots into cats there anymore.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the latest update, ocelot cannot be tamed. You can find and tame a Stray Cat in any village, but ocelot can no longer be turned into cats. They will trust you and allow you to get close to them, but will not actually be tamed.

This is due to requests for the ability to spawn a specific breed of cat, instead of spawning hundreds of ocelots and taming them, just to get a specific breed. Mojang has decided to make the ocelot a completely separate animal from the cat.